# replace hex value to random hex value with the same length in pcap file

Tags: bash, debian, sed, wireshark, tshark

I need to replace hex value to random hex value with the same length in pcap file.

I work in debian 10 in bash.

I have pcap file for example with this tcp payload in some packets:

[image: tcp payload]

I want to replace in all packets of the pcap file value `delta` to any random value but with the same length.

So, I tried this command

```
sed -Ei 's/\x64\x65\x6c\x74\x61/'$(openssl rand -hex 5)'/g' test.pcap
```

but pcap file will be broken after this command.

In pcap file I have a lot of tcp sessions with this part of payload `deltaRevocationList`. And I need in all packets and all tcp session replace `deltaRevocationList` to `RANDOM_TEXT_RevocationList`.

For example,  replace deltaRevocationList to

`abcdRevocationList` in the first tcp payload segment

`aaaaRevocationList` in the second tcp payload segment

`hcnfRevocationList` etc

How can I resolve this issue? With sed, tshark or editcap tools

For example I added sreenshot from wireshark what I want to see
[image: changed payload]

Comment: [edit] your question to replace the images with text that we can copy/paste to test with so we can help you.